# How to retrieve the auto generated primary key in postgres with ActiveJDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, activejdbc

in ActiveJDBC

If I have a `serial primary key` in the table with column name `id`

```
Employee e = new Employee();
        e.set("name", "John");
        e.set("age", 43);
        e.saveIt();
```

how is possible to retrieve it after saving the record?
I want to retrieve in order to insert an address for that employee:

```
Address d = new Address();
     d.set("employee_id", ???); // what to do here?
     d.set("address", address);
     d.saveIt();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, ActiveJDBC will do this automatically. 
Here is the same code that will properly set the ID:

```
Employee e = Employee.createIt("name", "John", "age", 43);
Address d = Address.create("address", address);    
e.add(d);
```

That was a short way of writing it. The longer version:

```
Employee e = new Employee();
e.set("name", "John", "age", 43).saveIt();
Address d = new Address();
d.set("address", address);
e.add(d);
```

In either case, you can get the Id from a model after you save like this:

```
id = e.getId()
```

For more information, refer: http://javalite.io/one_to_many_associations